# How to refresh the DOM tree in Selenium so newly generated elements are shown?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom, selenium-chromedriver

I want to get a DOM element which is not existent on page load, but is added afterwards using a script. The exact scenario is as follows:

1. I load up https://www.binance.com/de/trade/pro/XRP_BTC
2. I click on the "TradingView" button
3. I select "Stochastic RSI" on the "Technical Ind" button.

(All those steps are handled by either the driver itself using `click()` or a Robot using key and mouse presses)

After I have selected the Stochastic RSI there are new DOM elements added without a page refresh. The ones I am looking for `<span>` elements with the class name `"pane-legend-item-value-wrap"`, those are generated after adding the "Stochastic RSI".

Calling `driver.findElements(By.className("pane-legend-item-value-wrap"))` gives me 0 results. I think thats due to the driver page source still being the one after immediately loading up the page for the first time. Is there a way to either refresh that page source or the DOM tree **without reloading the whole page**?

I tried it with implicit and explicit waits, still without success and the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of any elements located by By.className: pane-legend-item-value-wrap (tried for 15 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

This is the relevant code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            Selenium selenium = new Selenium();

            selenium.startChrome();

            for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {

                try {
                    selenium.getChromeDriver().getTitle();
                } catch (WebDriverException e) {
                    i = 30000;
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println("Current Coin Value: " + selenium.getValueOfCoin() + "$ - " + "StRSI Blue: "
                        + selenium.getBlueStRSI() + " - StRSI Red: " + selenium.getRedStRSI());
                Thread.sleep(200);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

```
public class Selenium {

    private ChromeDriver chromeDriver;
    WebDriverWait wait;
    private Robot robot;

    public Selenium() throws AWTException {

    }

    public void startChrome() throws InterruptedException, AWTException {

        robot = new Robot();
        String pathToChromeDriver = "resources/driver/chromedriver.exe";
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", pathToChromeDriver);
        chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        chromeDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(chromeDriver, 15);

        chromeDriver.get("https://www.binance.com/de/trade/pro/XRP_BTC");
        Thread.sleep(200);
        chromeDriver.findElement(By.className("DEMrI")).click();
        Thread.sleep(200);
        chromeDriver.findElements(By.className("csajsa")).get(0).click();
        chromeDriver.findElements(By.className("bEXbyP")).get(6).click();
        chromeDriver.findElements(By.className("bEXbyP")).get(5).click();

        setStochRSI();

        chromeDriver.findElements(By.className("mt9q6r-1")).get(1).click();

    }

    private void setStochRSI() throws AWTException, InterruptedException {

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        robot.mouseMove(650, 250);
        mouseClick();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        robot.mouseMove(500, 310);
        mouseClick();
        robot.mouseMove(877, 205);
        mouseClick();
        robot.mouseMove(1250, 650);
        Thread.sleep(100);
        robot.mouseMove(0, 0);

    }

    public Double getValueOfCoin() {

        return Double.parseDouble(chromeDriver.findElement(By.className("sc-1yysggs-0")).getText().substring(12));

    }

    public Double getBlueStRSI() {

        String value;
        value = wait
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.className("pane-legend-item-value-wrap")))
                .get(9).getText();

        return Double.parseDouble(value);

    }

    public Double getRedStRSI() {

        String value;
        value = wait
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.className("pane-legend-item-value-wrap")))
                .get(19).getText();

        return Double.parseDouble(value);

    }

    public ChromeDriver getChromeDriver() {

        return chromeDriver;

    }

    private void mouseClick() throws InterruptedException {
        robot.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        Thread.sleep(50);
        robot.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    }

}
```

Comment: If it's visible on the page, it's in the DOM. Sounds like you probably need to add a wait for it to be visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason you can't find the elements is that because they are in "iframe". you should first switch to the iframe context and then click. Here is a working example:

```
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

    driver.get("https://www.binance.com/de/trade/pro/XRP_BTC");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@class='sc-1t2bpae-5 bEXbyP' and contains(text(),'TradingView')]"))).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='sc-1t2bpae-5 bEXbyP' and contains(text(),'Technical Ind')]"))).click();
    WebElement frameElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, \"tradingview\")]")));
    driver.switchTo().frame(frameElement);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Stochastic RSI')]"))).click();

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("pane-legend-item-value-wrap"));

    driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to either refresh that page source or the DOM tree?

call `get()` again, or use `navigate().refresh()`

Comment: That just refreshes the page causing the same process to happen again.

Comment: correct... that answers the question you originally asked... before you edited it to clarify.

Comment: Right. Seems like I forgot to state that specifically, now its somewhat clear :). Thanks anyways